# Why IResourceChangeListener Does Not Listen to Workspace Resource Changes

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

IResourceChangeListener can't listen to resource changes, I think this question is similar [How to add IResourceChangeListener in eclipse plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244316/how-to-add-iresourcechangelistener-in-eclipse-plugin)

I think greg-449's comment may be a reason. What should I do next? I want to continue using IResourceChangeListener? I don't know where to start modifying this question.Thanks in advance.
  I Override the `postWindowOpen()` method in the class `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor` to set up the resource listener,code like this:

```
@Override
    public void postWindowOpen() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.postWindowOpen();
        IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
           IResourceChangeListener listener = new IResourceChangeListener() {
              public void resourceChanged(IResourceChangeEvent event) {
                 System.out.println("Something changed!");
              }
           };
        workspace.addResourceChangeListener(listener);
    }
```

Comment: Properly set up resource change listeners definitely do see all workspace resource changes, You need to [edit] your question and provide a lot more detail. How are you setting up the listener? Is it seeing any changes? What changes is it not seeing?

Comment: @greg-449 I Override the postWindowOpen() method in the class ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor to set up the resource listener,If I modify the resource file and save it, it will not print out “something changed”，Is my resource listener set correctly?

Comment: When I display the refresh workspace, the resourceChanged method is called and prints "something changed"

Comment: My Navigator (providing the navigation tree) and Editor (editing the graphical model) are all self-defined and don't use various editors provided by eclipse

Comment: So how are your navigator and editor changing resources? Are they using the `IFile` APIs (which should work) or are they using plain Java APIs such as `File` (which won't work without extra code)?

Comment: Thanks a lot .After checking, I found that the IFile APIs are used to read the file, and the files are modified and written using the File APIs.But I try to After I saved the modified file successfully, I tried to use `IResource res= ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().findMember(filePath);
res.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_ZERO,null);` Let the workspace know that the resource has changed, but the workspace is not refreshed

Comment: refreshLocal should work provided you have the correct resource. Check the filepath, check that findMember is returning the resource you expect.

Comment: According to your suggestion, I succeeded when the resource listener prints "something Changed" when the resource changes, but the Navigator (TreeViewer) is not refreshed, ie navigator does not display in real time when node is added or deleted in editor.

Comment: Well what have you done to make the tree viewer refresh? You have to write quite a lot of code to process the `IResourceDelta`s in the `IResourceChangedEvent` to update the tree.